# Differenze di uso tra "numero" e "cifra" in contesti quotidiani

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, synonym

Non mi è chiaro quando si usa la parola "cifra" e quando invece si adopera "numero" in contesti quotidiani.

Al numero **1.c** della [voce "cifra" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cifra/) ho trovato che una delle accezioni di questo vocabolo è

> Numero in generale

Vuol dire questo che i due termini, "cifra" e "numero", si possono utilizzare indistintamente? (quando "cifra" ha questo significato: non mi riferisco alle altre accezioni del termine "cifra").

Per esempio, mettiamo che scrivo un documento in cui appaiono parecchie quantità come percentuali e altri dati espressi con un numero seguito da una unità (37 persone, 28 voti, 45 giorni, 22ºC, 2,5 cm, 67,99€, ...). Passano parecchi giorni e decido di fare pubblico questo documento. Mi accorgo, però, che alcune di queste quantità hanno cambiato il loro valore. Cosa dovrei dire?

- Devo aggiornare i numeri che appaiono nel documento.
- Devo aggiornare le cifre che appaiono nel documento.

Comment: Informalmente si usa talvolta “cifra” per dire “numero” in generale, ma io personalmente, parlando di numeri, uso “numero” per indicare un numero (e se voglio un sinonimo uso “valore”, “grandezza” etc.) e uso “cifra” solo per indicare una fra 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 (o eventualmente quelle esadecimali etc.). Cioè, “1982” è un numero, ma sono quattro cifre.

Comment: Ah, OK, @DaG: questo è anche l'uso a cui sono abituata io in altre lingue (beh, non esattamente, perché in catalano abbiamo "xifra", "nombre" e "número": si dice, per esempio "el número de telèfon" o "el número de pàgina", però "el nombre de pàgines que té el llibre" o "és un nombre irracional"), ma in italiano ho visto tante volte "cifra" usato per indicare quello che per me è un "numero" (o un "nombre" nella mia lingua)... A dire il vero, però, anche "xifra" (cat.) e "cifra" (cast.) si usano a volte in questo modo, soprattutto per quantità di soldi (ma non solo).

Comment: Personalmente associo al termine cifra il costo di qualcosa, ed in effetti treccani.it specifica espressioni  quali *cifra tonda, una bella cifra, una grossa cifra etc*.  come sinonimo di numero è un uso meno comune secondo me.

Comment: @Hachi: Ma, l'esempio che ha messo egreg nella sua risposta, cioè, "la cifra dei contagi", non è di uso comune? La mia impressione è che, di questi giorni, ho visto molti esempi di questo tipo.

Comment: questo risultato da Google Books, seppur con i suoi limiti, mi sembra indicativo dell’uso di cifra rispetto a numero: 1) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cifra+dei%2Cnumero+dei&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccifra%20dei%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumero%20dei%3B%2Cc0 2) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cifra+di%2Cnumero+di&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccifra%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumero%20di%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Hachi: In "numero di" appaiono espressioni del tipo "numero di matricola", "numero di Dunbar", "numero di telefono", "numero di cartella", "numero di mappa", "un gran numero di maniere diverse", "numero di Erdős", "numero di pagina", etc. Sono espressioni in cui chiaramente non si può adoperare "cifra".

Comment: @Hachi:  Anche in "numero dei" appaiono molti esempi appartenenti ad ambiti tecnici, scientifici, matematici (che non sono oggetto della domanda: capisco che in un contesto di linguaggio tecnico dovrei dire "il numero dei denti della ruota" o "il numero dei lati del poligono", per esempio).

Comment: @Hachi: Nell'esempio concreto che ho posto nella domanda, tu diresti "devo aggiornare i numeri che appaiono nel documento"? (si tratta di una vera domanda rivolta a te)

Comment: Sì, userei cifra/e solo se si trattasse di prezzi.

Comment: @Hachi:   Forse è più utile fare questo tipo di comparazioni: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cifre+dei+morti%2Cnumeri+dei+morti&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccifre%20dei%20morti%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumeri%20dei%20morti%3B%2Cc0

Comment: oppure così  :)https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cifre+di+morti%2Cnumeri+di+morti&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccifre%20di%20morti%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumeri%20di%20morti%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Non sto dicendo che l’uso di cifra sia sbagliato. Ti ho dato quello che per la mia esperienza e l’uso che sento e leggo fare e io farei. Cifra è un termine fortemente legato  a prezzi e costi, perlomeno questa è la mia percezione. In tutti gli altri casi io userei numero.

Answer (score 2):

Ovviamente, da un punto di vista matematico, *cifra* e *numero* hanno significati diversi: ogni cifra è un numero, il viceversa è falso.

Più precisamente, *cifra* è il simbolo per denotare un intero fra zero (compreso) e la base del sistema di numerazione (escluso); con le cifre si costruisce la rappresentazione di ogni numero nella base scelta. Ma, anche nella pratica matematica, non si fa troppa distinzione tra numero e sua rappresentazione, perché per *menzionare* un numero devo adoperare una sua rappresentazione.

Nel parlare comune, *cifra* è spesso adoperato come sinonimo di *numero*, sia al singolare sia al plurale; come sinonimo di *quantità* al singolare. In certi casi è addirittura obbligatorio: si può sentire

> mi è costato una cifra!

ma non si può adoperare *numero* o *quantità*. In questo caso sta per *grande quantità di denaro*.

A sensazione, l'uso di *cifra* invece di *numero* potrebbe denotare uno stile più ricercato:

> C’è ancora un giorno peggiore del precedente nella cronaca della lotta al coronavirus in Spagna. Così la *cifra dei contagi*, 94.500, si avvicina inesorabilmente a centomila; e le morti da Covid-19 stabiliscono il nuovo record quotidiano: 849, fino a formare il totale provvisorio di 8.100. E fino al prossimo bollettino.

[(Corriere della sera, 20 marzo 2020, corsivo mio)](https://www.corriere.it/esteri/20_marzo_31/coronavirus-spagna-virus-fuori-controllo-super-ospedale-incompleto-cosi-c-piu-rischio-contagio-che-cura-6e0eb906-735f-11ea-bc49-338bb9c7b205.shtml).

Qui dire *il numero dei contagi* sarebbe stato normalissimo. Nell'esempio di *aggiornare le cifre*, va benissimo; direi, sempre a orecchio, che *aggiornare i numeri* sarebbe troppo generico e preferirei *aggiornare i valori*; *le cifre* può riferirsi sia ai valori sia proprio alle cifre in senso tecnico: per modificare un valore, quindi un numero, devo agire proprio sulle cifre.

La distinzione che c'è in catalano fra *número* (rappresentazione, quindi successione di cifre) e *nombre* (numero in senso astratto, quantità) non esiste in italiano se non in ambito matematico: la rappresentazione di un numero è un *numerale*; in logica matematica, la distinzione è molto importante. La dimostrazione dei [teoremi di Gödel](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremi_di_incompletezza_di_G%C3%B6del) si basa molto su questa distinzione.

Comment: Questa distinzione tra i termini "número"  e "nombre" esiste in catalano, ma non in castigliano. In spagnolo non c'è una parola equivalente al catalano "nombre".

Comment: @Charo Corretto, avevo equivocato. Può interessarti sapere che in esperanto esistono *numero* e *nombro* con la stessa distinzione. Ma anche in francese, *numéro* e *nombre* hanno gli stessi usi che in catalano.

Comment: "Cifra" ha, rispetto a "numero", una più forte componente semantica di "quantità" o "valore". Perciò si può dire (anche se non è bello) "la cifra dei contagiati" (cioé la quantità dei contagiati), ma non la "cifra di telefono". Anzi, "numero di telefono" non sarebbe neppure del tutto corretto perché si tratta in realtà di un codice, di "un nome" fatto solo di cifre, che "ricorda" un numero, ma non lo è. Parlando di un documento che cità quantità, preferirei dire "le cifre sono da controllare" piuttosto che i numeri.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  In italiano, a differenza del catalano o il francese (che hanno due vocaboli diversi) la parola "numero" si usa per esprimere tanto una *quantità* come un *simbolo* formato da cifre (nel senso dei segni 0, 1, 2, ...). Per questa ragione, "numero di telefono", "numero di targa", ecc. sono espressioni perfettamente corrette: perché non dovrebbero esserlo?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Non capisco del tutto bene cosa vuoi dire con la frase «"Cifra" ha, rispetto a "numero", una più forte componente semantica di "quantità" o "valore"». E poi, in che senso "cifra di morti" non è bello?

Comment: @Charo Ai numeri puoi applicare operazioni e confronti, ai numeri di telefono e targhe no.
Il significato vero di numero (https://educalingo.com/it/dic-it/numero) è molto distante, perciò dico
che "numero di telefono" non è *del tutto* corretto; è un identificativo (difatti in certi testi viene definito così). Inoltre, su certi apparecchi telefonici a ogni cifra corrispondono alcune lettere, e tu potevi, almeno negli USA, combinare un nome (es. COMPUSERVE) per eseguire la chiamata.

Comment: Per cifra e numero, poi, nelle contrattazioni (d'acquisto) si  discute normalmente "della cifra" (l'importo da pagare), non "del numero". Alla frase "Quanto costa? 100 euro" non si commenta con "il numero mi sembra alto", ma molto più probabilmente con "la cifra mi sembra alta". Potrei citare altre sottigliezze, ma non ho tempo.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Infatti, non è il numero che è alto in sé, ma il *prezzo*, che è espresso da un numero *accompagnato dall'unità di misura*. Il numero 10¹² è grande, ma 10¹² pm (picometri) è lo stesso che un metro.

Comment: @egreg la domanda verte sulle differenze tra *cifra* e *numero*, e nessuno dei due termini significa prezzo. E' naturale poi che esprimendo giudizi sulla grandezza di cifre o numeri, il giudizio sia relativo al contesto (e non solo all'unità di misura), quindi 3 picometri, o 3 anni luce, possono essere tanti o pochi, indipendentemente dall grandezza del numero e dall'unità di misura usata.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Nel contesto del tuo esempio, “la cifra è alta” si riferisce alla quantità di denaro, cioè al *prezzo*.

Comment: Beh, @egreg, "grande" è sempre relativo a qualcosa: "grande" in senso assoluto non ha senso.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Veramente l'accezione **1.c** della voce "cifra" del Treccani che ho linkato nella domanda è, per l'appunto, "somma di denaro".

Comment: @egreg certamente, in quel contesto la cifra si riferisce al prezzo. Vi sono altri contesti dove "cifra" significa altro; io volevo solo far notare che *numero* e *cifra* non sono parole equivalenti, e non volevo fare polemica ma dare idee.

Comment: @Charo Il numero mille miliardi *è* grande in senso assoluto: prova a fartene una rappresentazione mentale con sassolini, monetine o caramelle. Mille miliardi di granelli di sabbia fanno ben più di mille metri cubi, ma nessuno veramente può immaginarsi di avere un cubo di sabbia di lato dieci metri e contare i granelli a uno a uno. Contando (molto velocemente), ci vogliono ben più di un milione di giorni per arrivare a mille miliardi.

Comment: @egreg:  Secondo me, nel momento che si cerca di fare una rappresentazione con sassolini, si sta paragonando a qualcosa (e allora diventa "relativo"). Ma, va be', lasciamo perdere...

Comment: @egreg:  Ammetto che si una quantità adimensionale ha il valore 10¹², allora direi che è grande: quindi, hai ragione (ma non posso pensare a sassolini).

Comment: @egreg aggiungerei che *cifra* e *numero* sono cose diverse non solo matematicamente: i numeri sono fatti di cifre, ma le cifre non sono fatte di numeri. *cifra* è un simbolo: per esempio  testo "cifrato" significa reso incomprensibile usando simboli diversi dagli originali.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Si tratta di un’altra accezione di *cifra*. E i numeri sono *rappresentati* con cifre (di solito), che è ben diverso; capisco che per molti la distinzione è sottile, ma qui dovremmo essere persone di cultura a cui interessa andare al centro delle cose.

Comment: @egreg stai dicendo che io non sono persona di cultura, o che non sto andando al centro delle cose? La domanda chiede "differenze d'uso tra numero e cifra", e io sto aggiungendo differenze. Ce ne sono anche altre che non ho riportato.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Non sto dubitando della tua cultura e sono sicuro che tu comprenda la differenza che ho sottolineato: per questo non mi va giù l'uso della frase “i numeri sono fatti di cifre”. Dobbiamo pensare a chi legge.

Comment: @egreg sono d'accordo che il termine migliore sarebbe stato *rappresentati* invece di *fatti*. Continuo a essere perplesso sui termini scelti da te per sottolineare quella cosa.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Mi scuso se l'espressione può essere presa come un rimprovero o peggio: non era la mia intenzione, tanto è vero che ho usato “dovremmo”, il che include me.